# IFS statement with SEARCH not working as expected

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Can anybody work out what's wrong with this?

```
=IFS(SEARCH("¬",C2),C2,SEARCH("¬",D2),D2)
```

The ¬ symbol is attributed to a winning team of two, placed in the C and D columns. In the event it's in the column of the team in C, it works, but otherwise not. Likewise if I flip instances of C2 and D2 around in the formula, it will work if the first condition is met that the team in D has ¬ present.

[image: here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IFS evaluates the list of conditions from left to right.  If the condition is FALSE, it evaluates the next condition.  As soon as it encounters a TRUE condition, it returns the associated result.  But as soon as it encounters an error, it stops and returns an error result.

In your example, row 4 works because it encounters a TRUE condition as the first one, returns the result and stops.  In the two previous rows, SEARCH does not find the target text when evaluating the first condition, so SEARCH returns an error.  That causes IFS to stop and display the error.

You could fix it by having SEARCH return a FALSE or `0` instead of an error if the target is not found.  Do that by wrapping the SEARCH expression with IFERROR.  It would look like this:

```
=IFS(IFERROR(SEARCH("¬",C2),0),C2,IFERROR(SEARCH("¬",D2),0),D2)
```

Comment: Superb. Thank you :)

Comment: And thanks also for editing my question. Will present it properly next time